# How to override 'Text wrapping' in Opera Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, opera, mobile-browser

I am trying to create a simple two column design, with two inline-block `<div>`s, using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">
body, html { 
   margin: 0;
}

#outer {
    background: #F00;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.col {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    background: #00F;
    margin-top: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div class="col">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div><!--
        --><div class="col">
            consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I have run into a problem with Opera Mobile (Opera Classic). That browser has a setting called 'Text wrapping' enabled by default. When turned off, the page renders as desired:

[image: Displaying correctly]

However, when the feature is enabled, it displays like this:

[image: Displaying incorrectly]

**Is there any way to override this functionality using HTML or CSS?**

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

try this meta tag

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the `#wrap` element, and `white-space: normal;` to the `.col` classes. I guess Opera Mobile interpreted the `divs` as 'textual' since they were inline-block.

Comment: Note that this solution is not ideal, since I would prefer the div's to wrap if the total width exceeds the screen size. Better solutions are welcomed.